Pandoc garbling header latex
I'm writing a document using markdown with latex headers, and converting them with pandoc with pandoc -s test.md -o test.pdf and debugging with pandoc -s test.md -o test.tex
However, it looks like pandoc is inserting additional characters into my headers and I'm not sure why. An example is:
---
keep-tex: true
header-includes: |
    \errorcontextlines 10000
    \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

    \definecolor{linequote}{RGB}{224,215,188}
    \definecolor{backquote}{RGB}{249,245,233}

    \newtcolorbox{myquote}[1][]{
        enhanced, breakable, 
        size=minimal,
        frame hidden, boxrule=0pt,
        sharp corners,
        colback=backquote,
        #1
    }
---

This is regular text

\begin{myquote}
This is custom quoted text
\end{myquote}

However, in the outputted tex file, the \newtcolorbox section becomes:
\newtcolorbox{myquote}{[}1{]}{[}{]}\{ enhanced, breakable, size=minimal,
frame hidden, boxrule=0pt, sharp corners, colback=backquote, \#1 \}

With additional curly braces in the parameter list, which is causing the tex to fail to compile. Why is this happening?

the {[} and also {suggests that pandoc doesn't know \newtcolorboxand so assumes everything after{myquote}` is text that is being quoted to prevent being interpreted by latex. I don't know pandoc details but can't you put all such definitions in a local .sty that is just included and not in the markdown sources at all?

You can stop pandoc from breaking your settings like this:
---
keep-tex: true
header-includes: 
    - |
      ```{=latex}
      \errorcontextlines 10000
      \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

      \definecolor{linequote}{RGB}{224,215,188}
      \definecolor{backquote}{RGB}{249,245,233}

      \newtcolorbox{myquote}[1][]{
          enhanced, breakable, 
          size=minimal,
          frame hidden, boxrule=0pt,
          sharp corners,
          colback=backquote,
          #1
      }
      ```
---

This is regular text

\begin{myquote}
This is custom quoted text
\end{myquote}


Beat me by 11 seconds, deleting my answer now :)

@Marijn Sorry!!! :)

Had to move the pipe back up to the header-includes line, otherwise I got yaml parser errors. Other than that though this worked perfectly, thanks!

@Epithet Which version of pandoc do you have? It work fine for me with pandoc 3.2.1

This is a viable syntax with Quarto markdown:
---
format:
  pdf:
    include-in-header:
      text: |
        \errorcontextlines 10000
        \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
        \definecolor{linequote}{RGB}{224,215,188}
        \definecolor{backquote}{RGB}{249,245,233}
        \newtcolorbox{myquote}[1][]{enhanced, breakable, size=minimal,frame hidden, boxrule=0pt, sharp corners, colback=backquote, #1 }
---
  
This is regular text

\begin{myquote}
This is custom quoted text
\end{myquote}

But a better (safer, clearer) YAML header could be some like:
---
format: pdf
include-in-header: 
  file: foo.tex
---

In case that foo.tex have some conflict with the default pandoc preamble (e.g. you load with foo.tex a package already loaded, causing the erorr Option clash for package ...), the better could be modify the default pandoc to include the new code but avoid the conflict, and just in the YAML header:
---
format: pdf
template: mytemplate.tex
---

